# Filter products by status in left navigation

Tags: php, magento-1.8

I want to filter product by status in left navigation.
Although i know code to get all enabled products here -

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id)
->getProductCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter(
    'status',
    array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
);
```

but i am not getting proper way to do this feature in left navigation.
Please help me.

Comment: Hello Need more description about your question ? To be more clear i mean you want only Enabled products to be listed in the Left Side Bar m i right  ?

Comment: Hi, Actually in left navigation filter where we filter products by attributes or category,like this i want one more option there to filter product by status means enable product.